# Using javascript to import data from pre-created XML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html

I think its my first post here! Used stackoverflow a lot, its a great website!

I have an XML file that contains amongst other things, a field that contains a file path to a particular file, a field that provides a created date, and fields that provide the latitude, degrees and seconds, and the longitude, minutes and seconds of images from a phone.

Part of the XML file is shown belows: (NB I have changed data in the file so it doesn't reflect "true" data.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OFSExport Version="4">
    <MobileDevice Name="785421076249232-01-01-2015 10-40-45">
        <Sections>
            <Section Name="FILE_BROWSER">
            <Item Type="ATTR_FB_TYPE_FOLDER">
                <Field Type="FLD_FB_FILE_PATH">/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/</Field>
                <Field Type="FLD_FB_MODIFIED" UTC_Offset="0"></Field>
                <Field Type="FLD_FB_LAST_ACCESSED" UTC_Offset="0"></Field>
                <Field Type="FLD_FB_CREATED" UTC_Offset="0"></Field>
                <Field Type="FLD_ITEM_HASH" Hash_Method="ATTR_HASH_SHA-2"></Field>

            </Item>
            <Item Type="ATTR_FB_TYPE_FILE" Deleted="ATTR_FB_DEL_ACTUAL">
                <Field Type="FLD_FB_FILE_NAME">IMG_1230.JPG</Field>
                <Field Type="FLD_FB_FILE_SIZE">716102</Field>
                <Field Type="FLD_FB_FILE_PATH">/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1230.JPG</Field>
                <Field Type="FLD_FB_MODIFIED" Date="17.01.2015" Time="18:16:09" UTC_Offset="0"></Field>
                <Field Type="FLD_FB_LAST_ACCESSED" Date="01.05.2015" Time="22:42:00" UTC_Offset="0"></Field>
                <Field Type="FLD_FB_CREATED" Date="17.01.2015" Time="18:16:08" UTC_Offset="0"></Field>
                <Field Type="FLD_ITEM_HASH" Hash_Method="ATTR_HASH_SHA-2">90e939f5bb4bad0ac53be9ad34db5bd98c4bc6628058ee9b5c3bcf4704f547bc</Field>
                <ExifInfo>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_ApertureValue" Eng_Title="Aperture value">2.27500712455432</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_BrightnessValue" Eng_Title="Brightness value">4.49876684478372</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_ColorSpace" Eng_Title="ColorSpace">1</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_DateTime" Eng_Title="Timestamp" Date="17.01.2015" Time="19:16:08" UTC_Offset="Device Time"></ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_DateTimeDigitized" Eng_Title="Digitized timestamp" Date="17.01.2015" Time="19:16:08" UTC_Offset="Device Time"></ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_DateTimeOriginal" Eng_Title="Original timestamp" Date="17.01.2015" Time="19:16:08" UTC_Offset="Device Time"></ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_ExifImageHeight" Eng_Title="Height">1920</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_ExifImageWidth" Eng_Title="Width">3412</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_ExifVersion" Eng_Title="Exif version">0221</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_ExposureProgram" Eng_Title="Exposure program">2</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_ExposureTime" Eng_Title="Exposure time">11:01:48 AM</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_Flash" Eng_Title="Flash">16</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_FlashPixVersion" Eng_Title="Flash pix version">0100</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_FNumber" Eng_Title="Focal number">2.2</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_FocalLength" Eng_Title="Focal length">4.15</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_FocalLengthIn35mmFilm" Eng_Title="Focal length in 35mm film">74</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_GPSAltitude" Eng_Title="GPS altitude">124.118556701031</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_GPSAltitudeRef" Eng_Title="GPS altitude ref">0</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_GPSDateStamp" Eng_Title="GPS timestamp" Date="17.10.2016" Time="00:00:00" UTC_Offset="Device Time"></ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_GPSDestLatitudeRef" Eng_Title="GPS dest latitude ref">E</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_GPSLatitudeDegrees" Eng_Title="GPS latitude degrees">40</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_GPSLatitudeMinutes" Eng_Title="GPS latitude minutes">30</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_GPSLatitudeSeconds" Eng_Title="GPS latitude seconds">10.00000000001</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_GPSLatitudeRef" Eng_Title="GPS latitude ref">N</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_GPSLongitudeMinutes" Eng_Title="GPS longitude minutes">15</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_GPSLongitudeSeconds" Eng_Title="GPS longitude seconds">31.0000000000001</ExifItem>
                    <ExifItem Type="FLD_FB_EXIF_GPSLongitudeRef" Eng_Title="GPS longitude ref">W</ExifItem>
```

I am a digital forensic examiner and I am trying to plot where pictures have been taken on a googlemap. the XML file is output provided by forensic software, and although it plots the data to a map in a very nice way, there doesn't seem to be a method to let others view it. So I am trying to create my own map with markers on it showing the location of where pictures are taken. I am using Google streetmap via HTML5 and javascript to do this.

The current plan is to loop through this XML file, pull out part of the file path, and the latitude and longitude data, add this data as a js object (fp:..., lat:..., lon: ....), and add this JS object to a JS array, and repeat till all the data is added. I will then loop through the array and create markers for each photograph on a map. (A future thought is changing markers for thumbnails of the image, and noting numbers of pictures in a particular location.)

For now I am trying to import the XML file and reference the bits I need, but I am struggling! I have tried **xhttp.open**, (the map will be a locally saved file that I will give to the customer afterwards, not saved to a server so this command doesn't work.) **$.parseXML** provides an error message of:

jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Invalid XML: geolocation.xml at Function.error (jquery.min.js:2) at Function.parseXML (jquery.min.js:2) at test.js:50

Does anyone know of a way to loop through an already created xml file that resides in the same folder as the HTML file using javascript?

Cheers

Bob

Comment: `jQuery` do the job for grabbing and parsing XML. Could you share your code?

Comment: @FieryCat  var testXML = $.parseXML("geolocation.xml");
 console.log(textXML);  cant get minimarkdown right!

Answer (score 0):

`parseXML` [use string for input,](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) try next solution:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "geolocation.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        // dataType do the job of $.parseXML(xml);
        console.log(xml);
    }
});
```

Comment: @ fierycat. Im receiving the following error: jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load geolocation.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ test.js:29                               Ive added the <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> in my html for jquery

Comment: XML files has to be on the same server, try to change `url` to a proper address: `url: '//' + window.location.host + '/geolocation.xml'